# Getting the value from input and checking it against a value jquery

Tags: jquery, input

Basically i have the 2 inputs:

```
<input type="text" style="height: 30px;" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" required><br /><br />
<input type="password" style="height: 30px;" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required><br /><br />
```

And basically,

I want to check the value in both these inputs, and check them to a said value (later to a database, but for check purposes now) and then fade into a new page..

How would i go about doing this?

I started it off..:

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        //do check
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You wan't this

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var username = $('#username').val(),
            password = $('#password').val();
        alert(username + ' ' + password )
    });
});
```

This is really simple stuff but `$('#username').val()` means get the element with the id username and get the current value of it

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nxzq/)

Comment: Now how would i check it against a value, then fade out and into a new page?

Comment: well you go `if( username === value ) { . . . }`

Comment: Ive done the check, I then do $('.content').fadeOut(3000); to fade out my original page, then how do i do the change page and fade in the new page?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the click button event but the submit event of the form (so it will work when the user press enter)

Remember to use return false in the end of the function.
To get a value of a input use .val()

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#form').submit(function(){
        var user = $('input[name="username"]').val(),
        pwd = $('input[name="password"]').val();
            return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: Now how would i check it against a value, then fade out and into a new page?

Comment: you check the value with conditional `if (valuea==valueb) {...}`, and if the value is right you haven't to write the `return false` , so that the form send the data to another page set in the action attribute of the form

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        console.log($'#username').val());
        console.log($('#password').val());
    });
});
```

Check this [Sample jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDFmp/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="container"><form name="myForm">
<input type="text" style="height: 30px;" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Username"    name="username" id="username" required><br />
<input type="password" style="height: 30px;" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required><br />   
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form></div>   

$(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
      var username = $("input#username").val().length;
      var password = $("input#password").val().length;

      if (username == 0){
          alert("Please enter your username");
          $("input#username").focus();
          return false;
      }
      else if (password == 0) {
          alert("Please enter your password");
          $("input#password").focus();
          return false;
      }
      else {
          //do a ajax form submit here and if it's success put below code in ajax success {}

          //removing all the contents form from the container div
          $("div#container").empty();

          //then load you next page (page you want to load after login success)

          $("div#container").fadeOut("fast");
          $("div#container").load("yourNewPage.html", function(){
             //fade in the div after loading the yourNewPage.html page 
             $("div#container").fadeIn("slow");
          });  

      }
  });
});
```